# Join results of multiple select statements in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, intersect

I have four select statements and I want to join them all to only get the common rows.

In an example, I'm providing 2 select statements:

```
SELECT 
    h.userid, 'Activity' as table_name, 
    h.stamp, 
    DATEDIFF(dd, kh.LatestDate, GETDATE()) as days_since, 
    m.group_name
FROM 
    ([Animal].[SYSADM].[activity_history] h
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT userid, MAX(stamp) as LatestDate
     FROM [Animal].[SYSADM].[activity_history]
     GROUP BY userid) kh ON h.userid = kh.userid AND h.stamp = kh.LatestDate)  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Animal].[SYSADM].secure_member m ON m.user_name = h.userid
WHERE 
    (DATEDIFF(dd, kh.LatestDate, GETDATE()) > 90)
    AND NOT (m.group_name = 'inactive')
ORDER BY 
    userid

SELECT 
    h.userid, 'Person' as table_name, h.stamp, 
    DATEDIFF(dd, kh.LatestDate, GETDATE()) as days_since, 
    m.group_name
FROM 
    ([Animal].[SYSADM].[person_history] h
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT userid, max(stamp) as LatestDate
     FROM [Animal].[SYSADM].[person_history]
     GROUP BY userid) kh ON h.userid = kh.userid AND h.stamp = kh.LatestDate)  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [Animal].[SYSADM].secure_member m ON m.user_name = h.userid
WHERE 
    (DATEDIFF(dd, kh.LatestDate, GETDATE()) > 90)
    AND NOT (m.group_name = 'inactive')
ORDER BY 
    userid
```

I have tried `INTERSECT`, but it's not returning any rows, I want to see the common rows from both the select statements (actually I have 4 so I believe what works for 2 will work for 4)

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I tried inner join on 2 select statements and it gave me the desired result but now the question is how I can use inner join on 4 select statements.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.userid as A_UserID, t2.userid as P_UserID, t1.stamp as A_stamp, t2.stamp as P_stamp, datediff(dd,t1.stamp,GetDate()) as A_days_since, datediff(dd,t2.stamp,GetDate()) as P_days_since, t1.group_name, t1.table_name, t2.table_name
from 
    (SELECT h.userid, 'Activity' as table_name, h.stamp, datediff(dd,kh.LatestDate,GetDate()) as days_since, m.group_name
  FROM 
 ( [Animal].[SYSADM].[activity_history] h
inner join (
    select userid, max(stamp) as LatestDate
  from [Animal].[SYSADM].[activity_history]
  group by userid
  ) kh on h.userid = kh.userid and h.stamp = kh.LatestDate
  )  
left outer join [Animal].[SYSADM].secure_member m on m.user_name = h.userid
where 
(datediff(dd,kh.LatestDate, GetDate()) > 90)
and not (m.group_name = 'inactive')) t1

inner join

    (SELECT h.userid, 'Person' as table_name, h.stamp, datediff(dd,kh.LatestDate,GetDate()) as days_since, m.group_name
  FROM 
 ( [Animal].[SYSADM].[person_history] h
inner join (
    select userid, max(stamp) as LatestDate
  from [Animal].[SYSADM].[person_history]
  group by userid
  ) kh on h.userid = kh.userid and h.stamp = kh.LatestDate
  )  
left outer join [Animal].[SYSADM].secure_member m on m.user_name = h.userid
where 
(datediff(dd,kh.LatestDate, GetDate()) > 90)
and not (m.group_name = 'inactive')) t2
on
    t1.userid = t2.userid
    order by T1.userid
```

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXX7A.png)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sure i will update my tag, its for sql-server

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: After viewing your query result you also need to add `DISTINCT` to each of the queries on the `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the `UNION` for a moment. Imagine you take that result and insert into `Table1`

Then depend what you mean the "common rows". If you want exact value but in different tables

```
  SELECT userid, h.stamp, days_since, m.group_name
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY userid, h.stamp, days_since, m.group_name
  HAVING COUNT( table_name ) = 2 -- in this case 2 because are two types 
                                 -- Activity and Persons
```

After viewing your query result you also need to add `DISTINCT` to each of the queries on the `UNION`.

Comment: thanks for the help, actually i just tried inner join with 2 select statements and it gave me the desired results but now i'm thinking about bringing rest of the 2 select statements.

Comment: As I said the `UNION` part is irrelevant. just change 2 for 4

Comment: Thanks, and from common rows I mean same rows returned by 1st,2nd,3rd and 4th select statement. I just want to ignore the rows which are not available in all 4 result sets and only want to keep which are available in all 4. hope this will help

Comment: Yes, looks like that is what I did here